# Inverse of series $z+a_2z^2+...$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $p$ be a power series with integer coefficients of the special form $p(z)=z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+..$. I wonder if the inverse (composition not $1/p$) series has again integer coefficients.

I have calculated some of such series so I guess yes. What do you think?

Comment: It depends on the series: in general the inverse need not to exist.

Comment: We can do better.  We can take the inverse as a power series around some point, with some requirements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Comment: You have deleted a lot of your own content recently. However, I also see that you are deleting your account.

Answer (score 2):

Given
$$
f(x)=x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\dots\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
g(x)=x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3+\dots\tag{2}
$$
formally, for $n\ge2$, the coefficient of $x^n$ in $g\circ f$ is
$$
0=a_n+b_n+\left[x^n\right]\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}b_k\left(x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\right)^k\tag{3}
$$
For $n=2$, $(3)$ says that $b_2=-a_2$. Then inductively, since $a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(3)$ guarantees that $b_n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Even if we only know for $2\le k\le n$, that $a_k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(3)$ guarantees that for $2\le k\le n$, we have $b_k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

For example:

$b_2=-a_2$
$b_3=2a_2^2-a_3$
$b_4=5a_2a_3-5a_2^2-a_4$
$b_5=14a_2^4-21a_2^2a_3+3a_3^2+6a_2a_4-a_5$

Comment: so there are polynomials $P_n$ with integer coefficients so that $b_n = P_n(a_2,\ldots,a_n)$

Comment: @mercio: indeed, as long as $a_1=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct, either you assume

1) the original series converges in some where as a Taylor series; or 
2) just "formal" calculations.

The key is you can list out a series of equations

b_1a_1=1

b_n + b_{n-1}a_1 + .. = 0 (n>1)

And you can decide one by one b_n.